# The plurals tag has lua syntax enabled

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, meta, syntax-highlighting

[image]

For some obscure reason - the [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) tag has lua syntax enabled.

This ought to be fixed, since it might get confusing if for some reason there's code in a question with such tag.

Could we remove the highlighting option as its not really appropriate?

Comment: And your master can't fix it himself? Not even by simulating a POST call to /tags/edit-tag-lang? Would be worth trying ...

Comment: Oh, sonic brought it up on chat. I'm at work and access to my main account is through my phone. I was both trying to make a point, and having something to point myself at later when I actually have access to my own PC. I've not given this a proper look yet. If not, well I'd have something to refer to when I poke around this in future

Comment: It's not really lua, but luas.